# How to use Socket.IO with ReactJS DnD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a board game using `Socket.IO` where each player's movements are immediately displayed on all other clients. I have used the `React DnD`(Drag and Drop) library to implement the dragging and dropping of board game pieces on my board, but I'm not sure how to implement the web socket part of the game where moves from each player are broadcasted to every other client.

Here is the url to the DnD library I used: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about

Comment: Hey I'm currently working on an application that has a similar use case. Did you find any good examples on how to implement your board game using both react-dnd and socket.io? If you did could you follow up on your initial post?